# WebdriverIO:-How to execute selenium script in already opened browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I know to execute the script in already opened browser by setting chromeOption setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress","localhost:1234") in webdriver.
I want to achieve this in WebdriverIO.
Is it possible?

Comment: Why you want to do that? What is the usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities

you can see that debuggerAddress is a chrome option , so you can do ut as :

```
capabilities: [
       {
            
            "goog:browserName": "chrome",
    
            "goog:chromeOptions": {
                "debuggerAddress": "localhost:1234"
    
            }
    
    }]
```